# Format values from a NSArray

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, nsarray, nsnumberformatter

I have a NSArray containing several strings that look like this: "291839.0930820"

I would like to format those values in the array so that they show up in my detailTextLabel of a UITableView with only 2 decimals: "291,839.09"

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: What is the class of the objects your array contains?

Comment: @H2CO3 I obtained the array in JSON from a website. It could be an array of strings.

Comment: In this case, try `cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", [[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] floatValue];`

Comment: @H2CO3 Thanks! It's working!.. But it is rounding to the nearest .50. What is the format to round to the nearest .01 ?

Comment: Keep in mind that `stringWithFormat` is not locale aware. Not all users expect to see decimal numbers with the `.` used as the decimal separator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To properly format numbers so the numbers appear correctly for a given user's domain is to use `NSNumberFormatter`. You should never usev`stringWithFormat:` for such purposes.

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init]:
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
[formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:2];

NSNumber *val = array[indexPath.row];
NSString *text = [formatter stringFromNumber:val];
```

**Update**:

I'm getting the feeling from Juan that the array doesn't actually contain `NSNumber` objects for the numbers but it actually contains `NSString` representations of the numbers. If this is the case, then one line in my answer needs to be changed. Change:

```
NSNumber *val = array[indexPath.row];
```

to:

```
NSNumber *val = @([array[indexPath.row] doubleValue]);
```

This will get the `NSString` from the array, then get the string's value as a `double`, and finally wrap the `double` in an `NSNumber`.

Comment: Thanks! But the last line of code "NSString *text..." is returning null when I try to NSLog

Comment: formatter is: <NSNumberFormatter: 0x72a5370>
val is: 10984694.898567000000000

Comment: Then `text` isn't `nil`. How are you logging `text`?

Comment: NSLog(@"Formatted value: %@",text);

Comment: I found out that the problem is that `NSString *text = [formatter stringFromNumber:val];` does not recognise "val" because it is part of an array. If I try setting "val" as a single number, the code works fine.

Comment: @JuanAndres That's what I showed in my answer. `val` is a single value. Of course my answer also assumes that the array contain `NSNumber` objects and not `NSString` objects.

Comment: @JuanAndres See the update I made to my answer. Based on your rejected edit, it seems you have strings in the array, and not numbers.

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like this if your array has float values

```
cell.detailTextLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.02f", [[array objectAtIndex:index]floatValue]];
```

Comment: This solution doesn't produce appropriate results for users in a locale that uses a different symbol for the decimal separator.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer, I have been using stringWithFormat forever, have not used `NSNumberFormatter` for myself but I am definitely going to try that , +1 for your answer

Answer (score 0):

lets say your value is `double value = 291839.0930820;`

You can construct a string like this

```
 NSString *formattedValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.2f",value];
```

assign this formattedValue to your textfield/label.

```
 cell.textLabel.text = formattedValue;
```